How to evaluate $\int_0^1 \left(\prod\limits_{k=1}^n (x+k)\right)\sum\limits_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{x+j}$?
I saw this integral
$$
\int_0^1(x+1)(x+3)+(x+1)(x+2)+(x+3)(x+2)dx
$$
which could be written as
$$
\int_0^1 \left(\prod\limits_{k=1}^3 (x+k)\right)\sum\limits_{j=1}^3 \frac{1}{x+j}=18
$$
so I tried to generalise this integral to
$$
I_n:=\int_0^1 \left(\prod\limits_{k=1}^n (x+k)\right)\sum\limits_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{x+j}
$$
at first I didn't expect the sequence to have a nice closed form but after computing the first nine integrals
$$
1, 4, 18, 96, 600, 4320, 35280, 322560, 3265920
$$
this sequence is $(n+1)!- n!$.
The only way I can think of to compute the sequence is to do the multiplication and then doing the integration and simplifying the terms which of course will not be sufficient to prove that then the $n$-th term of the sequence has the form $\left(n + 1\right)!- n!$.

Duplicate targets found instantly with Approach0

@MartinR If there is a tool than can find similar question and dup questions then Why the "Related" list can't find questions instantly?

Approach0 is a 3rd party project and not integrated into the Math SE search. For math-related stuff, it is much more powerful in my opinion. You may find this helpful: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265/42969.

Write $$P_n(x)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}(x+k),\qquad Q_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac1{x+k}.$$
Then notice that
$$\log P_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\log(x+k),$$
so that
$$\frac{d}{dx}\log P_n(x)=\frac{P_n'(x)}{P_n(x)}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{x+k}=Q_n(x).$$
That is, $P_n(x)Q_n(x)=P_n'(x)$, so that
$$\int_0^1P_n(x)Q_n(x)dx=\int_0^1P_n'(x)dx=P_n(1)-P_n(0)=(n+1)!-n!$$

$$P_n=\prod\limits_{k=1}^n (x+k)=(x+1)_n$$
$$S_n=\sum\limits_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{x+j}=\psi (x+n+1)-\psi (x+1)$$
According to my old cookbook (I do not remember the proof of it)
$$\int P_n\,S_n\,dx=(x+1)_n$$
$$\int_0^1 P_n\,S_n\,dx=n \,\Gamma (n+1)$$

the first one comes from the relation $P_n' = P_n S_n$, the second one is then easy.

@Yimin. Thanks for remembering me !
